# Unable to list files in google drive using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

Not sure if this has to do with my code or something on the Google side, however I'm able to push files to drive, but for some reason I cannot list the file/folder metadata inside a folder.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'creds.json'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

topFolderId = '0AAYXadsMHp8IUk9PVA'

items = []
pageToken = ""
while pageToken is not None:
    response = service.files().list(q="'" + topFolderId + "' in parents", pageSize=1000, pageToken=pageToken, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items.extend(response.get('files', []))
    pageToken = response.get('nextPageToken')
```

Any ideas here, I don't think it's permissions related as I'm able to put files in Drive, just not list them.

Comment: what's the error?

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot .execute()

```
try:
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(q="'" + topFolderId + "' in parents",
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
        return
    print('Files:')
    for item in items:
        print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
except HttpError as error:
    # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from drive API.
    print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
```